# google play rejected my app new version, they said that Xupdate sdk exists in the APP

Tags: google-play

we submitted a new release to google play. however, it was rejected by google. they said that a sdk named Xupdate exists in the APP.
However, we didn't import Xupdate sdk in the project.
could anybody help us, how to solve this problem? Thanks!

[here is the screenshot of google's reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIjXY.png)

[screen shot of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyf2y.jpg)

we removed any code about Xupdate in the project, and tried no less than 3 times to submit the app to google.
and we tried to search the problem with Google, but didn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the apk analyzer to check any references to Xupdate you might have: [https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer#view_dex_files](https://You%20can%20try%20the%20analyzer,%20and%20check%20any%20references%20to%20Xupdate%20you%20might%20have:%20https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer#view_dex_files)